# Designing an IoT product

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, arm, microprocessor, esp8266

This is more of a general question of the embedded electronics industry. At the moment I'm planning on building a device with a similar requirement to the Nest products. Essentially, I want to have a WiFi hotspot from this device that I can connect to with a nice browser UI and can see live sensor data.

My initial approach was to use an Arduino and an ESP8266 to achieve a prototype and then to create a PCB using just the Arduino's ATMega328P MCU with the ESP8266. However, I soon realized that displaying nice interfaces and incorporating a standalone ESP8266 IC itself on a single all-in-one PCB isn't really possible.

I'm now looking into use an ARM Cortex based chip like the STM32 which is what Nest actually uses in one of their products along with another ARM Cortex based NXP chip. After looking through STMicroelectronics site, I could only find full WiFi modules compataible with the STM32. There was no WiFi IC or anything.

I see so many companies that have these really nice UIs and intuitive ways of connecting their IoT to your home network with a nice browser setup process. However, when you look at the hobbyist area, it usually only has a single browser page with one text line displaying the sensor data.

**My question is: is it feasible for a single individual to be able to produce a standalone product with a single PCB that incorporates an MCU/WiFi functionality for IoT operation? And if so what's the best route for me to go?**

Comment: Use a Raspberry-Pi?

Comment: @Oldfart I'm looking to be able to produce a small custom PCB. Raspberry Pi would be far too big and I think I don't need all that functionality. My question is - how do actual established IoT companies like Nest do it?

Comment: It is entirely possible, it just needs some more work. Hobbyist projects tend to be the "simplest thing that works" (which is often a webpage with one line of text) unless the aesthetics are part of the project idea. They don't have to look nice to sell because they aren't selling anyway. But they could, with some more time investment.

Comment: Raspberry Pi Zero W. There is really **no** reason to do barebones if you don't have extremely tight size restrictions.

Comment: @Janka - a pi isn't viable as a product, since you can't replicate it for volume cost reduction.  By the time you volume source an SD card that isn't fake, you're at almost twice the cost you need to be at for that functionality, with a lot more that can go wrong.

Comment: This question will (or at least should) probably be closed as too broad.  But it seems the major thing missing from your consideration is surface mount sub-modules.  Typically for a moderate volume product, especially with RF, instead of dealing with the bare IC, what you'll do is get the radio and/or computer component as a sub module, and surround it with your custom product circuitry.  If you look at something like a NodeMCU ESP8266 or similar ESP32 board, you'll see that's how they are actually made, a sub-module on a carrier.  You can also look at router chips sold as IoT modules.

Comment: I don't think anyone here talking about "a product" mean more than a few hundred pieces. Not taking engineering costs into account is the key mistake young entrepeneurs make.

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear. I'm doing this project first of all to introduce myself into the ARM MCU world which I feel is much closer to what actual products use than Arduinos/Pi's. I find it hard to learn about new things without having a project to go along with it. This is a learning experience, by the end of it I hope to have a "product" that I could sell (no more than a few hundred). This is more of an advanced prototype much closer to actual product hardware than Arduinos, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Size & Components

I'd say that if you're interested in minimizing size, choosing to use a WiFi board such as the ESP8266 along with the Arduino's large chip (Assuming you mean DIP form) isn't the most space efficient route, but I think you've figured that out.

If you want to continue with the Arduino's chip for ease of programming you could get it in a smaller, possibly SMD, format, and find a suitable WiFi module to accompany it. One that I found with 2 min of searching is the [ESP8266 ESP-01](https://www.gearbest.com/transmitters-receivers-module/pp_338585.html), which seems to work with Arduino, as I found a page of projects [here](https://www.hackster.io/esp/products/esp8266-esp-01)

The ESP8266 (Full board version) (or at least the one I have beside me) is 60mm x 31.5mm which is only slightly smaller than the [Raspberry Pi Zero W](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3400) at only 66.0mm x 30.5mm x 5.0mm. I assume your initial rejection of the Raspberry Pi didn't consider the multiple forms it comes in. It's only $10 and would allow a great suite of programming options with a large community. You could also just simply program the ESP 8266!

The other option if you really desire to do a custom PCB is to use a WiFi enabled MCU such as the [TI CC3120](http://www.ti.com/product/CC3120/description). These types of chips would throw a lot more hurdles at you in terms of soldering, programming, designing, troubleshooting, etc. But power to ya' if you wanna tackle that! Hopefully this helps.

### Feasibility

Of course it's possible for a single individual to take on this sort of project. I currently am! I'm using BLE instead of WiFi but I have the same goals. Large companies have teams of people who pack their devices with every feature you could need and make beautiful UIs and have UX specialists making the experience amazing. They just put a lot more time into their presentation. But, for a hobbyist, you only want to transmit sensor data which isn't nearly as monumental, or beautiful, of a task. I'm not as much into the programming side but you could most definitely achieve this if you want to put in the effort.

Comment: There's little reason to use an Arduino alongside an ESP8266 - the ESP8266 is a substantially better computer than an Arduino.  A pi will add a lot of complexity, and it's not really viable for a *product*, only as a proof-of-concept mock-up.

Comment: Very informative response! Just one more thing, the TI CC3120 seems a bit too daunting to get into ARM-based MCUs. The STM32 has much more resources(development boards, guides, etc.).I feel like the STM32 is the easiest way of getting into ARM-based platforms.  Is there any WiFi chip that I could use in conjunction with the STM32?

Comment: Thanks Chris Stratton, after reading Taniwha's response and made an edit. AlfroJang80, there definitely is! I linked to the [ESP8266 ESP-01](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13678) above which is just one example of a board you could use. To use a chip you would have to do a lot of extra engineering using discrete components and RF design is very difficult. (I'm struggling with it currently!) Most of the "WiFi modules" you'll see have done this work for you. Though, If you want to dive in and do this for yourself, you could copy a schematic into your design or choose a chip and make it work

Comment: I ran out of space in that comment above, but an example of a chip would be [the WiFi chip from the ESP 8266](https://gridconnect.com/esp8266-wifi-chip.html). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

it's completely feasible - though I'd ditch the Arduino, the ESP-8266 can be programmed using the Arduino dev platform and has more flash/sram and CPU oomph than most Arduinos (pro-tip get the software load over wifi working, it's far faster for software dev)

If you want BLE as well choose an ESP-32